# How to find users in iOS

Tags: ios, networking, geolocation

I was wondering how to find users (who use the same app) through geolocation within a certain distance around you in iOS? If any has any tutorials/sample projects it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Unless there is some iOS specific API for this (which I doubt) it's likely that you would have to implement this yourself, through an on-line service that you run and that your users log in to. That's not trivial at all.

Comment: @Pekka웃 there is an api for this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a server to record all users' location, and when a user want to see users around, he make a request to the server, the server make some calculation to detect users within a certain distance, and return the result.

Comment: Would there be any tutorials for this.. or any pointers at how to build such a system?

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering if you are looking for MultiPeerConnectivity

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328

This is on ios 7 but it allows you to find nearby devices using the same application.

Comment: Interesting - here's an article about it. http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/ It seems, however, limited to devices on the same network or withing bluetooth range. It's not for *any* client within a certain distance. Either way, you could add it as an answer to the duplicate?